# Why does this program show something else even though the code is correct?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 4;
    char alpha[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
    {
        for (int b = 5; b > a; b--)
        {
             printf("%c", alpha[b]);
        }
        a--;
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want this code to print like this:

```
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
```

but the output it currently showing is this:

```
F
3
```

I don't know whether there is any typo cause i have checked a lot i thing i have done something 
else as wrong. if it's a typo just tell me it's because of typo if don't please help me with this as i am new to c programming language.

Comment: What can it possibly mean to say that "the code is correct" if it doesn't solve the problem that you set out to solve? The title of your question makes no sense. Perhaps you simply mean that the code compiles. So what? The world is full of buggy code that compiles. Such code should not be described as "correct".

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and consider using [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) to convince you that your program is correct. You might specify the behavior of your program using [ACSL](https://frama-c.com/acsl.html)

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, your outer `for` loop has a `;` at the end, so it has an empty body:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
```

---

Note that you should *always* compile with warnings enabled (e.g.):

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror foobar.c
```

If you had, the compiler would have flagged this statement.

---

gcc:

```
foobar.c: In function ‘main’:
foobar.c:7:9: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
         for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
         ^~~
foobar.c:8:9: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
         {
         ^
```

---

clang:

```
foobar.c:7:35: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
                                  ^
foobar.c:7:35: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning generated.
```

---

Note that newer versions of `gcc` don't need `-Wextra`.

`clang` will flag the statement with just `clang -c foobar.c`.

And, originally, `gcc` produced a similar "empty body" warning to clang's

Comment: It is quite interesting to see for me not for the first time, that clang seems to be more sensible by default (without additional compiler flags/options). I already made the experience at others issues.

Comment: As recommendation for beginners, I also like to advise `-Werror` because there is no escape/way to ignore the warnings.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, absolutely--edited. `-Werror` should be done, even for experienced programmers. I always do it. I leave it off only when the existing codebase produces leaves it off (e.g. linux kernel) where one would have to fix a slew of warnings that the upstream maintainers should fix themselves.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio  A footnote: I inadvertently introduced such an empty body error (on an `if`) to a 1000 line file. I was using `gcc -Wall -Werror` but didn't know about `-Wextra`. After triple checking, I was "convinced" the compiler was generating incorrect code. I rebuilt with `clang` and got the warning. Then, I experimented and discovered `-Wextra` [which turns on `-Wempty-body`] for `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

> "*Why the programme is showing something else even though the code is correct?*"

Because you got a semicolon `;` at the end of the head of the first `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
```

This will cause that the *presumed* loop body is not treated as loop body. It is treated as a compound statement *after* the first loop has been completed.

That is why you get this output.

---

Remove the semicolon and your program will print:

```
F
3
FE
2
FED
1
FEDC
0
FEDCB
-1
FEDCBA
-2
```

---

Furthermore, Remove `printf("%d\n", a);` to get the expected output of:

```
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
```

---

I also real recommend you to read the clues in [Craig´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62233171/12139179) regarding compiler flags and to never ignore compiler warnings as this is a code issue a compiler can, and dependent upon the compiler also by default, warn you about.

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected output remove `;` at the end of first loop and remove last `printf`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
    for(int b = 5; b > a; b--) { 
        printf("%c", alpha[b]); 
     } 
     a--; 
     printf("\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop has `;` at the end. There is no body. It does nothing.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the semi-colon at the end of first loop which you placed by mistake

Answer (score 0):

There are a small typo causing a major problem in your code:

- you have a spurious `;` at the end of your outer `for` statement. The `;` is an empty statement, causing the `for` loop to iterate with an empty body, and its intended body to be executed unconditionally once after the loop.

I would advise to use the Kernighan and Ritchie bracing style that makes this kind of error very unlikely:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 4;
    char alpha[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int b = 5; b > a; b--) {
             printf("%c", alpha[b]);
        }
        a--;
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```